# Extending CI_Controller

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, extend

All I'm trying to do is something fairly simple :

- Create a class (let's say `brandNewClass` - NOT `MY_Controller`) which extends CI_Controller
- Create other controllers which extend `brandNewClass`

**E.g.**

```
class brandNewClass extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

    }

    public function info()
    {

    }
}
```

used like (in a file under `/controllers`) :

```
<?php

class newController extends brandNewClass
{
}

?>
```

The thing is, although it works when I'm copying the file under `/application/core` and naming it as `MY_Controller`, when I change the name to something more... self-explanatory, it doesn't.

> **Fatal error:** *Class 'brandNewClass' not found in .... on line ..*

I've even tried using the `__autoload` function mentioned [here](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-39043-post-230503.html#pid230503), but without any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at this excellent tutorial - I hope it helps

http://codeigniter.tv/a-10/Extending-the-core-MY_Controller-and-beyond

Comment: @AJ - Not sure why as their main site is still up and running - http://codeigniter.tv

Answer (score 8):

The autoloader doesn't automaticly include other controllers. you will have to include it manually like this:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))exit('No direct script access allowed');

    include_once(APPPATH . 'controllers/brandnewclass.php');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a custom base controller and make other controllers extend there, you can do it in following ways:

1. Create `MY_Controller` extending `CI_Controller` in `application/core/` folder and make other controllers extend `MY_Controller` as `MY_Controller` will be autoloaded from core (This I guess you already know but want other alternatives.
2. Create `MY_Controller` in `application/core/`. Then create other level of Controllers that can primarily be `Admin_Controller` and `Frontend_Controller`. Now, one of these controllers will make base for your actual used controllers.

e.g. in `application/core/MY_Controller.php`

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Then Admin and Frontend controllers will be created in `application/libraries/` and will extend `MY_Controller` like

```
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Now, Any controller can extend one of these 2 controllers but for doing that you will have to autoload them. For autoloading in this case there can be a confusion because setting autoload['libraries'] in config/autoload.php will not work . That autoload works inside a controller but here we need to autoload before that i.e. in the class declaration. Will need to set this code in `config/config.php`

```
function __autoload($class) 
{
  $path = array('libraries');

  if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {
    foreach($path as $dir) {
        $file = APPPATH.$dir.'/'.strtolower($class).'.php';
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file))
            @include_once($file);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can create your own controller

```
class newController extends Admin_Controller
{
}
```

This is the most suggested method making your structure quite clean and effective. May take some effort in understanding for the first time but is definitely worth it.

3. Third method is just a tweak of the second one, just based on the condition you mentioned of not using `MY_Controller`
   You can make `Admin_Controller` or `Frontend_Controller` extend `CI_Controller` directly and not extend `MY_Controller`
   That may just lead to some duplicity of code in both these controllers if that may be the case

Comment: You can simply place `Admin_Controller` and `Frontend_Controller` in the same file of `application/core/MY_Controller.php` in this way you won't need to use the `function __autoload`

Answer (score 2):

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY
I suspect you're trying something similar?
There's an autoload function that you can add to the config file so that you needen't require_once() the class all the time.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should declare the class as abstract, since it shouldn't be instantiated directly.
2. You'll need to modify the CodeIgniter autoloader [configuration file](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/autoload.php) and add your class to it, or change the [actual autoloader](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php).
3. You really should consider not using CodeIgniter :)

Comment: Code Igniter 3 is horrible.  Code Igniter 4 may be better, but the way it was designed isn't very good.  They were also dogmatic about some strange things such as lack of support for an ORM...etc...